# Arduino Uno with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SSID "name-of-my-network" //replace XXXXX by your router SSID
#define PASS "password-of-network" //replace YYYYY by your router password
#define IP "184.106.153.149" //thingspeak.com IP

const int tempPin = A0; //configure Arduino pins
String GET = "GET /update?key=thingspeak-api-key&field1=";
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11); //Serial communication to ESP8266 module(RX, TX)
unsigned long starttime;
unsigned long sampletime_ms = 30000;
unsigned long delay_time = 60000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while(!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  //communication with wifi module
  mySerial.flush();
  mySerial.println("AT");
  delay(2000);
  if(mySerial.find("OK")) {
     Serial.println("Communication with ESP8266 module: OK");
   } else {
     Serial.println("ESP8266 module ERROR");
   }
   connectWiFi(); 
   //initialize timer
   starttime = millis();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if ((millis() - starttime) >= sampletime_ms) {
    char buffer[10];
    int analogReading = analogRead(tempPin);
    String temperatureStr = dtostrf(analogReading, 4, 1, buffer);
    temperatureStr.replace(" ","");
    updateSensors(temperatureStr);
    //wait next sampling cycle
    Serial.print("Wait ");
    Serial.print(delay_time/1000);
    Serial.println("s for next sampling");
    Serial.println();
    delay(delay_time);
    //initialize new cycle
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Sampling (");
    Serial.print(sampletime_ms/1000);
    Serial.println("s)...");
    starttime = millis();
  }
}

void updateSensors(String tempStr){
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += IP;
  cmd += "\",80";
  mySerial.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);
  cmd = GET;
  cmd += tempStr;
  cmd += "\r\n";
  delay(1000);
  int strsize = cmd.length();
  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND=" + String(strsize));
  delay(2000);
  mySerial.print(cmd);
  if(mySerial.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("Transmission completed with success");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Transmission failed!");
  }
}

boolean connectWiFi(){
  Serial.println("Connecting wi-fi...");
  String cmd ="AT+CWMODE=1";
  mySerial.println(cmd);
  delay(2000);
  mySerial.flush(); //clear buffer
  cmd="AT+CWJAP=\"";
  cmd+=SSID;
  cmd+="\",\"";
  cmd+=PASS;
  cmd+="\"";
  mySerial.println(cmd);
  delay(5000);
  if(mySerial.find("OK")) {
    Serial.println("Connection succeeded!");
    return true;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
    return false;
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I am using the above code and have connected the ESP8266 to the Arduino as follows:

> TX of ESP8266 to pin number 11 of Arduino
>   Rx of ESP8266 to pin number 10 of Arduino
>   Vcc of ESP8266 to 3.3V power supply taken from Arduino
>   GND of ESP8266 to GND taken from Arduino
>   CH_PD of ESP8266 to GND

It seems that I can't get the ESP8266 working. Could anyone could help me? I would really appreciate any help since I cannot continue my project.

Comment: Does your ESP module have the [AT firmwware](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT)?

Comment: If you interconnect two serial devices, the RX of device 1 is connected to TX of device 2. You appear to have connected RX to RX and TX to TX.

Comment: `CH_PD of ESP8266 to GND` should be at 3.3v instead of 0v...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the issue with this module is that the 3.3v of Arduino is unable to maintain enough current for the ESP8266 to work properly. I assume you have the proper firmware flashed to the wifi module

Comment: Yes, you are right. After many different attempts p, I figured that out. When I use the module with h a 3.3V FTDI, it works perfectly. When I use it with Arduino, data that is being sent to or received from the module, is corrupted. Arduino can't supply enough current to the ESP8266 module.

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to upload temperature data on pin A0 to things speak 
Create thingspeak account and create channel you get api key it seems that this code uses field1 to upload data upload this code to arduino the change ssid and password